# My Gravatar isn't associated with my user

Tags: support, gravatar

My Gravatar isn't showing on Stackoverflow or here on Meta.  Everything checks out fine on Gravatar's site, and I'm using the same email address for all 3 accounts.  So what's up?

My Gravatar is definitely G-rated so what's up?

Comment: Is it your DisplayName in some kind of starburst array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes at least 24 hours before you will see it.

Comment: In my case I think this was the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They use very aggressive caching. Wait a day or two.

Alternatively if you use gmail or another provider that supports this register a new gravatar account using the email `youraddress+something@gmail.com`; after that upload your avatar and change the email on stack overflow (doing it in this order is very important)

Comment: Ahh! I had a different mail set at stackoverflow! Thanks!